# Application throws SQL exception when running as startup

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, startup

I am working on a C# winforms Desktop application. The application has two processes. Users need to invoke only first process and first process will invoke the second process. The first process makes all web service calls to get the data and stores on local database. The second application is UI based and show data that is there in the local database. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express for local database.

This model works fine when the user clicks on the desktop icon or invokes from start menu. But my requirement is to start the application at windows startup. So I put the shortcut to first application in windows startup. In this case I see SQL exception for the database calls made on the second process saying Login failed for user `sa`.

The code for starting the second process is as below called from Form Load of 1st process

```
string MAIN_APP = "second.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MAIN_APP);
GetDataFromServer();
```

I do not have any clue why it works when invoked from desktop and fails in startup. I tried setting user context as administrator in application manifest but that is not solving the issue.

Any pointers on what could be wrong?

Code on the second application are as below:

```
try
{
    string sqlStr = "select remember_pass, imgfile from user_profile where  userid = '" + txtUserId.Text + "'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mainConnectionString)
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   logger.log("Caught Exception. Reason {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Note: I rectified the mistakes in the problem statement.

Comment: There's not enough code to analyze this. Show how your second application logs in to the database.

Comment: Please read your post because it's not really clear. Example: `my requirement is to start the application at the start of the application`

Comment: @Fabske if you read the entire post, it's pretty obvious that sentence should read _"to start the [second] application at the start of the [first]"_.

Comment: The service takes a while to start and you aren't waiting long enough.  Stop between the two commands for a few minutes and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @jdweng nope, _"SQL exception for the database calls made **on the second process** saying Login failed"_.

Comment: "I do not have any clue why it works when invoked from desktop and fails in startup." - You have the benefit of being able to see the code but we are being asked to help without seeing any code!

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue is seen then the application is set to start at windows startup. Sorry about not providing clear problem statement.

Comment: Does your application run on the same server than SQL server ? do you use windows authentication for sql connections ? or login/pwd ?

Comment: SQL Express is on the same machine as the application. I am using SQL Server authentication for login.

Comment: Exactly.  The second process cannot be run until the Service is running.  The process will return before the service is start so you will get an error if you run the second process too quickly.

Comment: The first process is storing data on the local database by making webservice calls. Also I tried bypassing authentication providing hard coded value.  After 5 minutes of start of the process I used the application to view data using the menu items. Then also I got errors. Also I tried to check for the existence of the sql server process by making the call Process[] procArr = Process.GetProcessesByName("sqlservr");

Comment: I face similar problem and the cause was same as @jdweng suggested, your SQLBrowser service might not running while your application starts. One suggestion could be like pause the application for some time (say one minute) so that OS properly started the SQLservice for you.

Comment: Ok will try adding delay to the application and see if that solves the problem

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your suggestion. I resolved the issue by adding a delay of 30 seconds. I modified code to open a database connection. If there are any exceptions then it will wait for 30 seconds and try again. I have the code in a loop of 4 iterations. If the connection could not be established in 4 iterations then I am showing Timeout error on UI. During my test I found that initial call is a failure, but after 30 seconds the call is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your service start before SQL Server is ready to handle connection.

Set your service as "Automatic (Delayed)" so that it'll start after the other services

More info on delayed start : http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx

Comment: Where does OP mention a Windows Service? They claim to have put the application in Windows Startup, which is only available after all services have started.

Comment: @CodeCaster correct. I do not have a service. I just put the shortcut to application program in Windows Startup.

Comment: @Prasanna then again, isolate the issue. Show how your application logs into the SQL Server. Do you load the connectionstring from the app.config?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am no using app config. During installation I have a module that shows UI for the admin to enter the details of SQL instance, user name and password. Based on the data entered, I generate the connection string and store in a text file. The application reads the file on form load and makes subsequent DB calls. The connection string is correct as it works when we start the application manually. The code to make database call is already mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Prasanna then please check how that file is loaded... The problem is not in the code you show. Perhaps the file cannot be found because of the startup path.